# How to separate this field into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a seamingly simple problem to solve that normally would be fairly easy. I've got a field that contains a DateTime portion, as well as a trailing text portion. I now need to split this field into two discrete fields - DateTime and Varchar. Now for the little gotcha. The data has been saved with two different date formats which has resulted in the filed looking a 'lot' like this:

```
amendmentnote
----------------------------------------------------------------------
30/07/2010 11:39:55: Booking status change from On Option to Cancelled
5/5/2010 10:1:8 : New
```

as you can see, the dates are in two completely different formats. I'd like to somehow see it parsed out as:

```
dateofnote          | note
----------------------------------------------------------------------
30/07/2010 11:39:55 | Booking status change from On Option to Cancelled
05/05/2010 10:01:08 | New
```

is this easily do-able??

cheers
jim

Comment: Does the text ever contain a ":"? Do the dates ever indicate AM/PM or are they always in 24-hour format?

Comment: Thomas - the dates are always 24 hr. thankfully, the text never contains a ':' character, so we can safely zoom into the last occurence if that's what you were thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily? No. Do-able. Yes, if we can make some assumptions. If it is the case that the text never contains a colon, you could do:

```
Declare @Data Table ( Data Varchar(max) )
Insert @Data(Data) Values('30/07/2010 11:39:55: Booking status change from On Option to Cancelled')
Insert @Data(Data) Values('5/5/2010 10:1:8 : New')

Set DateFormat DMY

Select Cast(Reverse(Substring(Reverse(Data), CharIndex(':', Reverse(Data)) + 1, Len(Data))) As DateTime)
    , LTrim(Reverse(Substring(Reverse(Data), 1, CharIndex(':', Reverse(Data)) - 1)))
From @Data
```

Answer (score 1):

It's do-able, but it'll be ugly.

You can use string functions to find the third colon in the **amendmentnote** field, and anything to the right of the third colon will be your **note**.

As for the date, you should again be able to use string functions to reformat the date portion, although you'll most likely need lots of substrings to make it work.

My only concern would be if the date formats entered are MM/DD/YYYY for one entry, and DD/MM/YYYY for the other.

Comment: yes, LBT, i think it'll be very ugly but it'll be a one hit 'upgrade' so will only ever run once (famous last words). as you say, the date formats for the 2nd date are always in the MM/DD format. the 'saving grace' could be that those entries ALWAYS have a space after the 3rd colon (oh it get's worse!!), so might be a logical way to discerne those... (going green now!!)

Comment: LBT - this certainly works for the notes portion. just that dang crazy mixed up date in it's couple of guises to contend with...

Answer (score 1):

Based on what's provided, use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 
               SUBSTRING(t.amendmentnote, 1, LEN(SUBSTRING(t.amendmentnote, 1, PATINDEX('%: %', t.amendmentnote)))-1), 
               103),
       LTRIM(SUBSTRING(t.amendmentnote, 
                       LEN(SUBSTRING(t.amendmentnote, 1, PATINDEX('%: %', t.amendmentnote)))+1, 
                       LEN(t.amendmentnote)))  
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Being a DATETIME, you can use [CAST/CONVERT to format it as you like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) - don't store "presentation" data.

Bad data is bad data - this is a mine field you'll have to navigate, isolating rows that won't match the pattern in the query & deal with appropriately.

Comment: omg  -thanks. i like the approach, tho have chosen another as the answer, +1 tho

Answer (score 0):

Once in a DateTime column, they'll be in the standard DateTime format.  How they're presented once queried at that point is up to you.

So, once you split your data into your `DateOfNote` and `Note` columns, you can Convert the `DateOfNote` to VarChar and apply a format to get what you want. 
`Convert(NVARCHAR, DateOfNate, 103)` will get you there (I think: double check the format style there at the end).

**Edit**  Based on your question, it looks like you wanted more help with the formatting.  However, on the splitting the column, you'll need to use string functions.  I'd find the index of that last colon, store it in a local variable, and then use `substring` to find the datetime (left of that last colon) and the note (right of last colon).